# textfield enable clear button but dont allow the keyboard to come up

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitextfield

Is there a way to have a UITextField with the text read only but still let the clear button work?  I have a set of buttons on my view that interact with the text field so i dont need the keyboard to pop but if i disable the text field. the clear button shows up but i cant press it anymore.  Is there a way to do this or should i make my own clear button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `clearButtonMode` to UITextFieldViewModeAlways, and have the delegate return NO for `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`.